# Screen scraping based on title using python bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem in screen scraping using bs4. Following is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
properties=soup.findAll('a',{'title':'Bedroom'})
for eachproperty in properties:
    print eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string
```

When I analyzed the website, the actual title structure looks like this

`1 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery` for all the anchor links. But I do not get any output for this and no error either. So how do I tell the program to scrape all the data that has the title containing the word `"Bedroom"`?

Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a regular expression here, as you only want to match those anchor links that have `Bedroom` *in* the title, not as the whole title:

```
import re

properties = soup.find_all('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
```

This gives 47 matches for the URL you've given.